# mobile vision ocr not download needed libraries

Tags: android, ocr

I am developing an app and using mobile vision api for text recognizing (OCR).
it was working perfectly since I clear all data from google play service.And now it dose not work.

My logcat is like this :

```
04-20 12:31:13.666 13375-14347/com.example I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
04-20 12:31:14.234 13375-14347/com.example I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
04-20 12:31:18.378 13375-14347/com.example I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
04-20 12:31:18.382 13375-14347/com.example I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: false
04-20 12:31:18.384 13375-14347/com.example W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
04-20 12:31:18.397 13375-14347/com.example I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
04-20 12:31:18.398 13375-14347/com.example I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1702
04-20 12:31:18.411 13375-14347/com.example I/Vision: Loading library libocr.so
04-20 12:31:18.412 13375-14347/com.example I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: false
```

I have enough storage and `if (hasLowStorage)` not hit:

```
    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {

                    IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
                    boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;


                    if (hasLowStorage) {
//Show some message to the user
    }
    }
```

in manifest I have included:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
```

and in my gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'
}
```

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue (on a device where my app worked, but stopped after an automatic update of Google Play Services).

I've resolved going in `Settings > Apps > Google Play Services > Memory` and then `Clear All Data`. Check for something similar (it can be different on different Android version).